# Put model data to form Spring MVC when load

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, validation

I have a problem when I try put data from controller to form view when **page load** in spring mvc.
Here is my Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("myaccount.htm")
public class MyAccountController {
    @Autowired
    private AccountValidation accountValidation;

    public void setAccountValidation(AccountValidation accountValidation){
        this.accountValidation = accountValidation;
    }

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringUTF8Editor(true));
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showAccountForm(Map<String, AccountForm> model){
        AccountForm account = new AccountForm();
        model.put("accountform", account);
        return "myaccount";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processAccount(@Valid AccountForm accountForm,
            BindingResult result, Map<String, AccountForm> model, HttpSession session, HttpServletResponse response) {


        //I try put something model like this when load page
        AccountForm acc = new AccountForm();
        acc.setEmail("h@gmail.com");
        acc.setBirth("12/12/1989");
        acc.setPassword("user");
        acc.setPhone(21767621); 

        // but it only show when I submit 
        model.put("accountform", acc);
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            return "myaccount";
        }

        return "myaccount";
    }
}
```

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not initialize this data during processing POST request, because it overwrites user's supplied data. Instead you should set default values in `showAccountForm()`. And even more: use [`@ModelAttribute`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#modelattrib) to fill model.